# how to find maximal matching pattern in data in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, linguistics

I have a format in a file called file.txt which has lines like:
babies:n:baby
flies:n:fly
ladies:n:lady
sheep:n:sheep
furniture:n:furniture
luggages:n:luggage
etc.
Now,i need to extract only the common pattern between f1 and f3 and want to write in the format:
example:babies
here, babies have common pattern till 'bab' and 'ies' is addition in the following words also.
Format:`<e lm="babies"><i>bab</i><par n="bab"/></e>`

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, it would be great if you can explain more.

but, i think that you want to use regex (regular expression).
here is a nice website to play with regex: https://regex101.com/

in python you can use the re module (import re).

if you have string like "babies:n:baby" , you can extract the similarity with the regex: `(\w+).*:n:(\1).*`
which mean: 
(\w+) - find sequence of alphabet chars
:n:   - and then find :n: 
(\1)  - and then the same word that we catch in the first ()

python sample:

for one search:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w+).*:n:(\1).*"
result = re.search(pattern, word)
return result.group()
```

and for many searches:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w+).*:n:(\1).*"
result = re.findall(pattern, word)
return result
```

Comment: I am making the question clearer. For example, I have a paradigm like this:  babies:n:baby; ladies:n:baby; fries:n:baby. I wanted ro make in the following format: <e lm="babies"><i>bab</i><par n="baby"/></e>; 
<e lm="ladies"><i>lad</i><par n="baby"/></e>
<e lm="fries"><i>fr</i><par n="baby"/></e>
similarly, I have multiple paradigms. I want a general rule to find the maximal match of words.